# Is WP feature image function cropping images? WP Content Slideshow

Tags: plugins, slideshow

I am using WP Content Slideshow. I like the plugin, but am having an issue with it. I mailed the creator, but no response, so I am trying to troubleshoot what is causing the problem. You can see the issue on the homepage of [elyconnect.com](http://elyconnect.com).

The plugin uses the featured image for the image in the slideshow. I set the resolution for each image size correctly, but the images are "cropping" and I dont know why.

I'm open to suggestions, or a recommendation for a better plugin if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think on your example is the picture to small for crooping;  if the image is smaller as the config on mediathek in WP, than it is not possible to crop the image. Your theme use the image from 300px width for this view and the css style defined 447px.

Comment: Good thought, it is probably themes CSS that is hijacking the resolution.